# Extracting data from binary file without reading the whole file - is this possible?

Tags: list-manipulation, import, binary

Suppose I have a binary data file that holds 1 million lists each composed of five integers. i.e. $\{ x1,x2,x3,x4,x5 \}$

Perhaps I am missing something obvious (quite likely) - but if I know I want to extract the 405,313th list and that list only - how can I do this?

From what I have read with BinaryRead etc. I have to read in the entire file. Not a big deal with say 1 million lists - but it is a big deal with 1 billion lists.

Ideas?

Comment: See [`Skip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Skip.html) and [`SetStreamPosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetStreamPosition.html) . You don't need to read in a whole file to seek to a position in a file.

Comment: @flinty - much appreciated. I'm tired but I didn't think that tired to miss this. Merci.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an example, lets write some binary data:

```
Export[nam = "test.bin", Range[126], "Binary"];
```

Then we open a stream in binary mode:

```
str = OpenRead[nam, BinaryFormat -> True]
```

Then we position the stream after the 8th integer:

```
SetStreamPosition[str, 8]
```

Finally we read a list of 3 integers and close the stream:

```
BinaryRead[str, {"Integer8", "Integer8", "Integer8"}]
Close[str];

(* {9, 10, 11} *)
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see this SetStreamPosition. Thanks for this.

Comment: It happens to all of us!